# Different Quick Launch on Pages

Tags: navigation, managed-navigation, url-rewriting

I have a site collection with 6 pages at the root. I have set up a term set navigation for better urls.

On one of those pages (not subpages) I would like to use other links in the quick launch like in the site collection root.

Is this possible?
When I make subsites out of the pages, first quick launch will be different. But as soon as I use term set navigation, the quick launch will display like in the root.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just overlooked that I have to create a new term set for my subsite to create different quick launch links.

But is this also possible with pages? Because now I have extra librarys on each subsite, which I do not need and are just overhead and confusing people.